# Changing user password on DigitalOcean PostgreSQL returns error must be superuser to alter replication roles or change replication attribute

Tags: postgresql, digital-ocean

I want to change the auto-generated password for `doadmin` user on DigitalOcean PostgreSQL 14. I'm using the following command:

```
ALTER USER doadmin WITH PASSWORD 'newpassword'
```

but this returns the following error:

> 42501 must be superuser to alter replication roles or change replication attribute

I'm using `doadmin` user credentials to execute this query.

Comment: That a replication user can't change their own password is by design.  Maybe you can get DO support to change the password to what you want for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DigitalOcean support confirmed it's not possible to change `doadmin` password on PostgreSQL but you can reset to another random password.

I guess it's a limitation of how PostgreSQL handle password changes because changing `doadmin` password on DigitalOcean MySQL is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update the `doadmin` password to a new password of your choice, but you can reset it to receive a new auto generated password.
See the [database user reset](https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/doctl/reference/databases/user/reset/) command.

```
doctl databases user reset <database-id> <user-name> <new-auth-mode> [flags]
```